# form confirmation before submit to mysql

Tags: php, forms, confirmation

I have worked on very large form and it’s submitting results to mysql very well. But I want to show confirmation of the entered form data so users can update it if there are any changes required before submitting it to mysql.

What should I use to achieve this? `$_POST` or `$_SESSION`? Please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: Depends on how much data the form is dealing with - POST would be preferrable, but Session might be the only real option.

Comment: Using jquery i believe you can stick whatever they are typing into the input fields on some sort of div form layout as a preview before allowing them to submit it.

Comment: have you tried to google JQuery? It would be actually http://jquery.com. JQuery will allow you to do it, but you'd still have to code it yourself for that to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely $_POST is the choice as it will not required to store again in sessions.
Just show the confirmation, if user selects yes, then you can insert them from the $_POST variable which you already have stored.

Comment: Does the data in the $_POST persist after the lifecycle of one request?

Comment: No, but tha's why the confirmation page should contain another form with all the POSTed data in hidden fields. When the user confirms, they actually submit that second form which contains the hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of both?

When the user submits the form, use $_POST to get the parameters and prolly some validation if you don't let javascript do it for you.

Display those parameters in another page together with the confirm button.

You can keep the input in the $_SESSION for a while and when the user confirms, send it to mysql.

Comment: i don't want to use both if until it's not required. I want to choose which one would be good to achieve this?

Comment: i think in your case it would be more efficient to store it in the session once it has been submitted for confirmation...unless you would want to write the form inputs in hidden input fields in the confirmation page.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JAVASCRIPT` validation for check validation of this form and if all fields having valid values then Submmit form via `POST` method.Now you will get all your fields in `$_POST`.

Thanks.

Comment: For validation, javascript isn't full proof. What if the user turns off javascript in the browser?

Comment: ya there will be problem if so, then you need to put validation with PHP in server side scripting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use POST for the non-cookie, non-javascript solution
the confirm page will have the previous form data in hidden field and the data will be submitted again with the Yes button

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple sample using jquery http://jsfiddle.net/robx/QBt5L/. Not formatted for anything, but you can get an idea from it, plus as mentioned, you should also consider JQuery validation for form validating to increase error submissions in required fields.